# Why does distutils.core.setup build shared extensions in 2 compiler invocations?

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py

`distutils.core.setup`, when told to build a shared extension module from a single C source file, does it in two steps:

In the first, it invokes the compiler and builds an object file with `-fPIC`.
A shortened commandline of this step could look something like this (at least on a unix system):

`gcc -pthread -I/usr/include/python3.8 -O3 -fPIC -c ./SOURCE.c -o build/.../ext.o`

In the second, it feeds the aforementioned object file to the compiler again, this time passing an additional `-shared` compiler flag, and produces a shared `.so` library file.

`gcc -pthread -O1 -shared ./build/.../ext.o -o ./build/.../ext.so`

---

This could surely be achieved in one singular step (I managed to manually reproduce a working extension using one compiler invocation) so why is it done in two? This is a pretty niche implementation detail but I'm very curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 1st run is compilation, it compiles `SOURCE.c` to `ext.o`. The 2nd run is linking, it links `ext.o` with the standard libraries and produces the final `ext.so`.

Why there are 2 separate runs is hard to say. Perhaps because `distutils`/`setuptools` are designed to be universal and use different compilers, not only `gcc`. See the list of supported compilers [in the source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/master/Lib/distutils); look at `*compiler.py`.